# Show/Hide Div if autocomplete input is selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I have two Angular-Material autocomplete fields added as [shown here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete) and it's working well so far.

Code of autocomplete:

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
    <md-autocomplete
    ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
    md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
    md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
    md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText2)"
    md-search-text="ctrl.searchText2"
    md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
    md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText2)"
    md-item-text="item.display"
    md-min-length="1"
    md-floating-label="Destination"
    ng-model="destiFlight">
    <md-item-template>
        <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>
        No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
    </md-not-found>
    </md-autocomplete>
</form>
```

JS:

```
.controller('someCtrl', someCtrl);
  function someCtrl($timeout, $q, $log) {
    var self = this;
    self.simulateQuery = false;
    self.isDisabled = false;
    // list of `state` value/display objects
    self.states = loadAll();
    self.querySearch = querySearch;
    self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
    self.searchTextChange = searchTextChange;
    self.newState = newState;
    function newState(state) {
        alert("Sorry! You'll need to create a Constituion for " + state + " first!");
    }
    // ******************************
    // Internal methods
    // ******************************
    /**
     * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
     * remote dataservice call.
     */
    function querySearch(query) {
        var results = query ? self.states.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : self.states,
                deferred;
        if (self.simulateQuery) {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.resolve(results);
            }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
            return deferred.promise;
        } else {
            return results;
        }
    }
    function searchTextChange(text) {
        $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
    }
    function selectedItemChange(item) {
        self.selectedItem3=item;
        $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
    }
    /**
     * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
     */
    function loadAll() {
        var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
                Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
                Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
                Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
                North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
                South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
                Wisconsin, Wyoming';
        return allStates.split(/, +/g).map(function (state) {
            return {
                value: state.toLowerCase(),
                display: state
            };
        });
    }
    /**
     * Create filter function for a query string
     */
    function createFilterFor(query) {
        var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
        return function filterFn(state) {
            return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
        };
    }
};
```

Now I have added a div below both the fields like this:

```
<div class="someDiv">
    ....
</div>
```

How can I show the div only if a value has been selected from the autocomplete dropdown?

Comment: Have you tried using `ng-show` and set it to the selected value? You need to show more of what you've done in order to get the full picture of what it is that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Another way can be `$watch`. Set a flag say 'source' and on change, check it and process it accordingly.

Comment: @Rajesh How does $watch works? I'm still learning angular so please don't mind the noob questions.

Comment: @Andrew, it's alright. $watch is a watcher on your variable. Whenever value of your variable changes, it will fire an event. This event also gives you access to old and new value. Benefit of $watch is if your variable value is changed from code itself, still this event is fired and hence you do not have to trigger any event

Comment: @Rajesh Oh I see. How do I use it for the autocomplete?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the model which stores the selected value for autocomplete:

Autocomplete:

```
<md-autocomplete
      md-selected-item="mySelectedItem"
      md-items="item in myList"
      md-item-text="item.name"
      md-min-length="0"
      placeholder="Select country">
```

And the div:

```
<div class="someDiv" ng-show="mySelectedItem && mySelectedItem.length != 0">
     ....
</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding ng-show like this Diana: ng-show="ctrl.selectedItem.length != 0" but the box is kept hidden even after a value is selected. I have updated the question with some more codes btw. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem can you create  aplnkr with your issue?

Comment: Diana, I can't seem to make the codes work (both on plnkr as well as jsfiddle) even though it's loading fine via my local files though :( Here's a link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/83/

Comment: Hm, I don't have a template locally that I can use for testing. Is it particularly this autocomplete you are interested in, or you just need autocomplete functionality?

Comment: The autocomplete is working fine Diana. But making a div appear only after a value is selected from the auto-complete field is where I'm stuck at unfortunately :(

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. Just was wondering if I cant help with this particular directive and it also doesn't work on plunkr/fiddle at least to try a different way (not using this directive) to achieve the autocomplete + div below to work together

Comment: Rajesh mentioned something about `$watch` earlier in the above comments but I'm not very sure how that works though.

Comment: yeah, watch can be used to track a variable change. But it is called on $scope and in your example you use a different syntaxt that is imposed by this autocomplete directive. The watch is `$scope.$watch(
"ctrl.selectedItem", function handleChange( newValue, oldValue ) {
console.log( "ctrl.selectedItem", newValue );});` try to call it over the `self` variable, but not sure if it will work.